# Horizontal Scroll Added Due to CSS

Tags: html, css

I have added CSS in my blog to create a kind of solid background by using div and styling it.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="asad">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Container contains the main content and aligns itself to center and it has width 80%vw and it is centered.

Here is the CSS:

```
div#asad {
    width: 100vw;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-left: -50vw;
    margin-right: -50vw;
    background-color: #4faefc;
    color: white;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

But this CSS introduced a horizontal scroll bar to my blog. How do I remove it? The resulting screenshot is given below.
[image: horizontal scrollbar issue]

I tried to hide the scrollbar via `overflow-x: hidden;` but it did not work.

The live example of the result I want is [here](https://backlinko.com/video-marketing-guide)

Comment: The way CSS is applied on the element is a bit strange: why do you need `left: 50%; right: 50%` and then with `-50vw` for horizontal margins? Those are probably causing the scrollbar to render. What about just using `width: <some value>; margin: 0 auto;`? Can you share a [mcve], since the markup in your question does not reproduce the bug you mentioned?

Comment: @Terry if I only use `width: <some value>; margin: 0 auto;`, It'll be limited to due container. Container won't let it go left and right.

Comment: Pretty sure that layout requirement can be handled differently.

Comment: @Terry is right about using `margin: 0 auto`, and about sharing some more code..